# Methods::GET not found in C++ REST

Tags: c++, rest, casablanca

I've built Casablanca and all other dependencies correctly in Ubuntu 16.04. But when I follow those C++ examples on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj950081.aspx) site, I found the program cannot find `methods::GET` member. It only shows `methods`, but no child member of it. What did I miss? 
Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

Here's the code I use:

```
#include <http_client.h>
#include <filestream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

// Creates an HTTP request and prints the length of the response stream.
pplx::task<void> HTTPStreamingAsync()
{
    http_client client(L"http://myAddressComesHere");

// Make the request and asynchronously process the response. 
return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
{
    // Print the status code.
    std::wostringstream ss;
    ss << L"Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << L'.' << std::endl;
    std::wcout << ss.str();

    // TODO: Perform actions here reading from the response stream.
    auto bodyStream = response.body();

    // In this example, we print the length of the response to the console.
    ss.str(std::wstring());
    ss << L"Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << L" bytes." << std::endl;
    std::wcout << ss.str();
});
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I already did. As you can see from the link I referenced, I delcared that namespace before.

Comment: I included test code and updated my question.

Comment: Any update on this issue? Can you post full error message and compilation commands?

Comment: No update at all, I used the code as shown above with Qt Creator. The toolchain is default gcc set by qt.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why your program does not find GET, no exact error was specified.
Also the documentation you are using is bit old, please try following samples from cpprestsdk's [sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) from github.

Anyway, as you specified Ubuntu 16.04, I assume you are using GCC. I am able to succesfully run your source code using only few modifications, full sample code:

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace utility;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace concurrency::streams;

pplx::task<void> HTTPStreamingAsync() 
{
    http_client client("http://www.google.com"); 

return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "Server returned returned status code " <<    response.status_code() << '.' << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss.str();

    auto bodyStream = response.body();

    ss.str(std::string());
    ss << "Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << " bytes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss.str();
});
}

int main() {
  HTTPStreamingAsync().wait();
}
```

Cpprestsdk compiled from sources. Program compiled using gcc 7.2.1:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/cpprest -o ct main.cpp -lcpprest -lboost_system -lcrypto
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also built from souce using gcc. However it still doesn't show me `GET` or any other child member for `methods`. I tried to read through the original `header` or `cpp` files of `web::http`, but still they don't seem to include these child members. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Gibet Unfortunately, no. The example code above also gives the same error.